# Force trailing slash with rewritecond and rewriterule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 4 lines of code here, and the first two for some reason force the trailing slash (so if you visit `login` it sends you to `login/`, but why don't the second two? I want it so if I go to `game/mmo` then it forces them to `game/mmo/`.

What code forces the trailing slash in the first 2 lines?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(register|login|recover)(?:\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(game)\.php\?game=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/ [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

The second only matches requests that look like this:

```
/game.php?game=mmo
```

**NOT**

```
/game/mmo
```

You need a different rule for that:

```
RewriteRule ^game/(.*[^/])$ /game/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you mind having a quick chat with me? I have a question regarding it.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73882/discussion-between-invidious-and-anubhava

Comment: @invidious sorry, wasn't at my computer. The first rule has a regex that matches `register` or `login` or `recover` with an optional `.php` extension then a space. That means it matches requests that look like `/register`, `/login` and `/recover`. No trailing slash, no extension. That's why it works. The second regex only matches requests that have the query string `game=`, that's why it doesn't work.